# Change of variables in a complex integral $\int_C^\ \frac{4z} {z^4 +6z^2 +1} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

I want to evaluate this integral using Residue Theorem

$$\int_C^\ \frac{4z} {z^4 +6z^2 +1}  dz = $$

$$ C  : |z| = 1 $$

so I substitute letting $$\ W = z ^ {2 } $$
 $$ dw = 2z dz $$

and the contour is $$ s  : |w| = 1 $$
 and go on normally
$$\int_s \ {} ^\ \frac{2} {w^2 +6w +1}  dw  $$

and I evaluate that using the theorem normally

the problem is the that the value is half of the correct value....what is the problem then ?

Comment: Change or variables should be essentially $1$ to $1$, i.e. $1$ to $1$ on a set of full measure. However, you map $z\mapsto z^2$ is $2$ to $1$ on $C$, which leads to the factor $1/2$.

Answer (score 6):

When you make your change of variable you can think of it like going from $\theta \in[0,2\pi]$ to $\theta\in[0,4\pi]$ if you write $z = e^{i\theta}$. Hence you will have a winding number of two and you'll pick up the factor of two that you are missing.